# Acquire lease on the same azure blob at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-blob-storage

Noticed the following behavior in my team’s application:

Multiple threads trying to acquire the lease on the same blob using the line below:

```
await blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lockTime), null, null, new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy }, null);
```

Multiple threads got a lease successfully, each got a different lease, around the same time.
This is because AcquireLeaseAsync is [NOT thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj682374(v%3Dazure.10)#thread-safety) right?
I thought lease is a lock, so it can only be granted to one thread at a time?

We tried to add an access condition of lease ID being null, which seems to be helpful.

```
await blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lockTime), null, new AccessCondition { LeaseId = null}, new BlobRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = RetryPolicy }, null);
```

But not sure if it’s fool-proof, i.e is there a chance multiple threads can pass this access condition when trying to acquire lease on the blob?

Below is the code that I use to generate this issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("started");
        var storageConnStr = "";
        var client = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnStr).CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("test");
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference("Program.cs");
        List<Task> list = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(Task.Run(() => AcquireLease(blob)));
        }
        Task.WhenAll(list).Wait();

    }
    static void AcquireLease(CloudBlob blob)
    {
        try
        {
            var id = blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null, null, null, null).Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully acquired lease on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, lease id {id}, time is {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Got exception at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

> Successfully acquired lease on thread 86, lease id
>   dfbd393e-46e2-49dc-98f4-853356fbc255, time is 11/10/2018 2:16:57 AM
>
> Successfully acquired lease on thread 22, lease id
>   f81b3dbf-68f6-401d-b82e-a1c19fb3527c, time is 11/10/2018 2:16:57 AM
>
> Successfully acquired lease on thread 54, lease id
>   6c05c2ee-c5a5-4d4e-83a9-b65688fca6df, time is 11/10/2018 2:16:57 AM

Comment: I believe the issue is that you're firing an async operation but not waiting for its response. I am sure if you wait for it, you will get an exception that lease can't be acquired.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for the response. If you look at the code I used, I think I do wait for the async operation to complete.

Comment: blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null, null, null, null).Result;

Comment: Also not sure why AcquireLeaseAsync depends on customer code to achieve leasing atomic?

Comment: have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: You seem to get atomic leasing if you add `new RequestConditions { IfNoneMatch = ETag.All }` to your `AcquireLeaseAsync` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

change `var id = blob.AcquireLeaseAsync` to `var id = await blob.AcquireLeaseAsync`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug in Azure Storage backend, but leasing does not seem to be atomic.

An undocumented solution which should resolve this is to force leasing to be atomic (it has worked in our internal testing, at least):

```cs
await blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    new RequestConditions { IfNoneMatch = ETag.All } // force atomic
);
```